# Why unicode word is not matching but english word will match with my regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi i'm trying to match the any give word if

1. if it begins with (same letters)
2. exact match (exact word)

My regex is something like this

`/(?<=[(["]\s*|\b)(टीम\w*|UAE\w*|afri\w*)(?=\b|\s*[\])"])/igm`

which works for english words but fails with hindi words

**Note:** my expectation is to match both english and hindi

Here is what i have tried [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/SGYeni/1)

**Problem:** my pattern is matching english words perfectly but not matching this hindi word `टीम`

Comment: I tested your regex and it matches `aटीमbcdef` but not `टीम`. I guess that's because `\w` can't match a Hindi character? I tried `\w+` with `टीम`, nothing matches.

Comment: @qrsngky  any other hint if you have please suggest me

Comment: @qrsngky direct pattern match also working https://regex101.com/r/qVRqKG/1

Comment: `\b` can detect the boundary between `' '` and `'U'`, but not between `' '` and `'ट'`.

Comment: An idea: `(?<=\s)टीम\S*` (not a solution yet)

Comment: @qrsngky it seems to be working, but i will verify all my test cases, you can convert that to an answer i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to come up with something:

```
(?<=[(["\s]|^)((टीम|UAE|afri)[^\]\s)"]*)
```

Please tell me if there are cases missed.

Comment: matching all the test cases thank you very much for the solution !!

Comment: I added a pair of parentheses in case you want to use $1 to refer back to the matched string

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that you tried does not match `टीम` due to the boundaries you have specified in the lookaround assertions.

The lookbehind `(?<=[(["]\s*|\b)` does not match because:

- There is no [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) on the left of `टीम`
- In the example data, there is also no occurrence of `(` `"` `[` and optional whitespace chars to the left
- The same in the opposite direction applies for the lookahead assertion

To get the matches, you could write the pattern as:

```
(?<![^(["\s])(?:टीम|UAE|afri)\w*
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!` Negative lookbehind, assert what is directly to the left is not

  - `[^(["\s]` Match a single character other than `(` `[` `"` or a whitespace char
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `(?:टीम|UAE|afri)` Match one of the alternatives
- `\w*` Match optional word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UkFfm8/1)

If you want to match word characters with `\w` and hindi characters, you can combine it using a character class `[\u0900-\u097F\w]*`

```js
const regex = /(?<![^(["\s])(?:टीम|UAE|afri)\w*/g;
const str = `इस बार टीम इंडिया के पास टी-20 वर्ल्ड कप में पाक के हाथों 10 विकेट से मिली करारी हार का बदला लेने का मौका होगा। एशिया कप UAE में हो रहा है। इस टी-20 टूर्नामेंट की शुरुआत africa`;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```